# Search content using date function

Tags: php, mysql

By using this function i have to search some content in the database by date. This coding works enough well. but i dont like to explode it. is this possible to search record by date using only strtotome() rather than explode??

```
function doSelectBranchRecords($objArray)
        {
            $strWhereClause = '';
            if ($objArray['frmNameSearch']) {
                $strWhereClause.= " AND A.branch_ident = '".$objArray['frmNameSearch']."' ";
            }
            if ($objArray['frmLoanSearch']) {
                $strWhereClause.= " AND A.loan_ident LIKE '%".$objArray['frmLoanSearch']."%' ";
            }
            if ($objArray['frmBeneficiarySearch']) {
                $strWhereClause.= " AND A.beneficiary_idents LIKE '%".$objArray['frmBeneficiarySearch']."%' ";
            }
            if ($objArray['frmDateSearch']) {

                $strDate = explode("-", $objArray['frmDateSearch']);
                $strAccountstarted = $strDate[2].'-'.$strDate[1].'-'.$strDate[0];

                $strWhereClause.= " AND A.account_started = '".$strAccountstarted."' ";
            }

        $strSqlSelect = "SELECT A.*, B.branch_name FROM tbl_companydetails as A,tbl_branchdetails as B where A.branch_ident = B.branch_id $strWhereClause order by company_id DESC";
        $strValues = SelectQry($strSqlSelect);
        return $strValues;
    }
```

Comment: Its doesn't work enough brother.. #Sunil omrey

Comment: sorry try this A.account_started = date($objArray['frmDateSearch'])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to replace

```
$strDate = explode("-", $objArray['frmDateSearch']);
$strAccountstarted = $strDate[2].'-'.$strDate[1].'-'.$strDate[0];
```

with

```
$strAccountstarted = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($objArray['frmDateSearch']));
```

if you don't need time than remove `H:i:s` from date.